# Keyboard doesn't work after Windows resume from sleep (S3) -- how to fix?

Tags: windows, keyboard, sleep, acpi

I have a weird issue with my keyboard after resuming from S3 sleep: I can type perfectly for maybe 5 seconds, but afterwards the keyboard ceases to work until I hibernate or restart *(or sleep again -- see below.)* The rest of my system runs just fine -- just the keyboard apparently "freezes" up.

Some closer observations:

1. The keyboard will work for 5 seconds (and freeze again) every time I resume from sleep, even if it was frozen from a previous sleep
2. The caps lock light will work fine within the 5 seconds. But after the keyboard "freezes", the light will remain on, but I'll be unable to turn it off. Perhaps this means power wasn't cut off from the keyboard, but it's just some software freezing up the port???

Given this info, would this indicate a problem with Windows itself? Drivers, maybe? Can I rule out the BIOS as the culprit? Finally, any ideas on how to fix? Thanks!

Specs:
Windows 7 x64
HP tx1000 laptop

Comment: Have very similar problem - all my USB devices don't work after Windows 7 wakes up from hibernate.

Comment: I have the same issue. Just recently updated my Win7 to SP1, maybe that's somehow related..

Comment: As I noted here: http://superuser.com/questions/480596/resuming-after-sleep-in-windows-7-causes-usb-keyboard-to-disappear?rq=1 my problem was caused by an entirely different PCI device acting up; I physically removed that device, and the problem with the keyboard disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with resuming from [S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode#ACPI) sleep a good deal of time ago, and it turned out to be an USB hub that did not like coming back from sleep. Try unplugging the keyboard or plugging it into a different USB.

Comment: Nah -- actually I'll clarify that this is my laptop's own keyboard. It's identified as a PS/2 device. I even set my USB hubs to disable powering down during sleep, and that had no effect...

Comment: I'd guess (but that's really just a guess) it's the drivers.  Have you gone to the device manager and checked if there are power replated options to the keyboard device (some devices have a power related tab in their "properties" there)

Answer (score 1):

First update the OS to the newest patches, then go to `hp.com` >> Support & Drivers, find the proper model and driver for the chipset and install it.

Hibernation/ sleep isn't working 100% fine. Many machines have problems when coming out of these states (Wi-Fi lost, audio lost, etc.).

Comment: Annoying isn't. Hibernation and sleep have been out for 15 years and there's still issues with it!

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue. My workaround is to use the [accessibility on screen keyboard to login](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/611f5858-87cb-4c04-9007-b0d7dc206c1e/how-can-i-make-the-on-screen-keyboard-display-at-the-login-page?forum=w7itproinstall) and then put the computer straight back into sleep, and then wake it up again. The keyboard then works. Annoying though!